# execute method in org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session is not defined (Spring Neo4j SDN 4 M1

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

Getting the following exception when I try to execute the query to create a relationship between nodes

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session.execute(Ljava/lang/String;)V    at
>   org.springframework.data.neo4j.template.Neo4jTemplate.execute(Neo4jTemplate.java:183)

I am using the following dependencies in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-ogm</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.M1</version>
        </dependency>
```

My code is something like in service POJO

private void createServiceRelationships(
            XXX yyyy, Neo4JExtension template)
            throws Exception {

```
    Boolean zzz = yyyy.getKKKKK();

    String queryBegin = "MATCH (n:XXX {pk:'"
            + XXX.getPk() + "' })";


    for (String LLLL : XXXX.getLLLL()) {
        String cipherQuery = ",(m:" + Name + "ROOT" + "{pk:'"
                + Name + "ROOT"
                + "' }) CREATE (m)-[:ROOT]->(n)";
        template.execute(queryBegin + cipherQuery);
    }

}
```

Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to include the neo4j-ogm dependency. In fact, with SDN 4.0.0.M1 you shouldn't. 
Please upgrade to SDN 4.0.0.RC1 - it contains many fixes and features since M1.